# Reversing AJAX call with browser back button

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm currently building a new portfolio site. I'm currently using Isotope for the layout of my portfolio items while loading the detailed info with AJAX. I'm utilizing CCS3 transitions to add some nice effects/transitions to the "detail" content. Clicking a portfolio item fades out the main portfolio grid, then replaces it with the work detail page. Following some things I found online, here is what I have so far that is working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('.item-wrapper a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.html .work-detail';
        $('.site-container').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});

$('.item-wrapper a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' .work-detail';
    $('.home').addClass('homeFade');
    setTimeout(loadContent, 900);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('.site-container').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('fast');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('.site-container').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('.work-detail').fadeIn('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('fast');


    }
    setTimeout(workFadeUp, 1300);
    function workFadeUp() {
        $('.work-detail').addClass('work-detail-show');


    }
    return false;

});
```

I originally had some problems with `$('.work-detail').addClass('work-detail-show');` as I was trying to add it as a callback function to `showNewContent()` but it seemed to act as if the `.work-detail`  wasn't available yet, so after a lot of trial/error I have it at the end with the delay now.

Basically its acting how I'd like it to, but now comes the part that, at this point, is over my head.  How can I go about programing this to where a user presses the browser back button, this AJAX call is somehow reversed... Fading out the work detail and fading the portfolio grid back in... all while updating the address bar?

I've looked into History.js but I'm somewhat a deer in headlights when reading through the README's.

I'm definitely not a jQuery/AJAX master, but am willing to dig... just feel like I've hit a rock.

Here is a link to my dev site http://bit.ly/U38SFB

Also, considering going the non AJAX route, as AJAX doesn't really enhance the usability/functionality just provides that "cool loading" factor I did create a fake AJAX version that runs the same CSS transitions and actually links to the page.

```
$(window)
.load(function () {

$('.work-detail')
    .addClass('work-detail-show');
});

$("a.fakeajax")
.click(function () {
$('.home')
    .addClass('homeFade');
var href = $(this)
    .attr('href');
// Delay setting the location for one second
setTimeout(function () {
    window.location = href
}, 700);

return false;
});
```

but still have the same problem, when pressing the browser back button, the added class to fade out the portfolio grid is still present.

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is something like:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "You are leaving the page"
}
```

You can put some other code to, let's say, send a request to the server to save some data... but, in the end, all this does is to annoy the client with a confirmation pop-up.

You cannot control the browsers buttons. They go throw the history of saved urls and load them.
Also, you are not allowed to modify the window.history entrys.